# Show that $\sum_{v=0}^N (-1)^v {N \choose v} \left(1- \frac{v}n\right)^r \to (1-e^{-p})^N$.

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

> (Feller Volume 1, Q.13, p.61) Let 
>   $$u(r,n) = \sum_{v=0}^N (-1)^v {N \choose v} \left(1- \frac{v}n\right)^r.$$
>   Show that if $n\to \infty$ and $r \to \infty$ so that $r/n \to p$, then $u(r,n) \to (1-e^{-p})^N$.

Although I am not sure if this exercise is related to the previous one, I have proved previously that
$$\frac{{n - N  \choose r-N}}{{n \choose r}} \to p^N.$$

But, this exercise involves sum and $(-1)^v$, and I am not sure how to proceed. I would appreciate if you give some hint.

Comment: the $(-1)^{v}$ is for $(a-b)^N=(a+(-b))^N$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left ( 1 - \frac{v}{n} \right )^n = e^{-v}$. Using this, we can see the following (as $n,r \to \infty$):

$$
u(r,n) = 
\sum_{v=0}^N (-1)^v \binom{N}{v} \left ( 1 - \frac{v}{n} \right )^r =
\sum_{v=0}^N (-1)^v \binom{N}{v} \left ( \left ( 1 - \frac{v}{n} \right )^n \right )^{r/n} =
\sum_{v=0}^N (-1)^v \binom{N}{v} \left ( e^{-v} \right )^{r/n}
$$

Now if we apply our knowledge that $r/n \to p$, we see how to simplify further to

$$ \sum_{v=0}^N (-1)^v \binom{N}{v} e^{-vp} $$

Finally, using the binomial theorem, we see that *this* is equal to

$$ (1 - e^{-p})^N $$

---

I hope this helps ^_^